# Проверка валидатором на наличия файла

Tags: node.js

Хочу сделать проверку на наличия имени пользователя и изображения.  Для всего приложения мне подходит [express-validator](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator), но он не хочет работать с файлами `req.files`. Я делаю так:

```
import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator/check';

router.post('/add', upload.array("photos"), [
    check('photos').exists().not().isEmpty(),
    check('name').exists().not().isEmpty()
], (req, res) => {
...
```

С `name` все работает хорошо, но в `photos` приходит `undefined` и выдает ошибку `Invalid value`, хотя я в `postman` загрузил 3 изображения.

Почему так происходит или как сделать проверку на наличия изображения в `req.files`?

Comment: Есть предположение, что проверку наличия изображения вам придется делать в обработчике `multer`, где, собственно, загружаются файлы.